# Changing the location specifier of a table breaks row spacing in LaTeX - Possible clash with package setspace

Tags: latex

I'm doing a report where I present several tables that cover almost 1 page, but there is still some space for 1 paragraph.
I'd like to be using the `[h]` (or similar, e.g. `[ht]`) location specifier to allow LaTeX to manage the remaining space, but when I change the specifier (from `[H]`, which is the only that maintains the correct row spacing) the row spacing is compressed, and I can't understand why nor how to correct this issue.

Here is a (stripped-down and adapted to an article) version of the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace} % for custom spacing (spaces)
\setstretch{1.3} % for custom spacing
% Tables
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\usepackage{lipsum} 

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\footnotesize} 

\begin{document}
Test here
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{My table with \textit{H} option}
  %\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}llrrrrr@{}}
  \toprule
  {\textbf{Dataset}} & {\textbf{Model}} & {\textbf{F-1}} & {\textbf{F-2}} & {\textbf{F-3}} & {\textbf{F-4}} & {\textbf{F-5}}\\
  \midrule 
  \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset1}} & Model0 & 0.805 & 0.800 & 0.840 & 0.817 & 0.853 \\
   & Model1 & 0.839 & 0.813 & 0.855 & 0.879 & 0.822 \\
   & Model2 & 0.840 & 0.811 & 0.855 & 0.880 & 0.825 \\
   & Model3 & 0.845 & 0.812 & 0.849 & 0.806 & 0.843 \\
   & Model4 & 0.846 & 0.814 & 0.850 & 0.808 & 0.844 \\
   \cline{2-7}
  & Model5 & 0.840 & 0.817 & 0.857 & 0.879 & 0.818 \\
   & Model6 & 0.807 & 0.891 & 0.835 & 0.816 & 0.857 \\
   & Model7 & 0.828 & 0.803 & 0.844 & 0.889 & 0.828 \\
  \midrule
  \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset2}} & Model0 & 0.448 & 0.417 & 0.659 & 0.376 & 0.477 \\
   & Model1 & 0.488 & 0.424 & 0.682 & 0.412 & 0.432 \\
   & Model2 & 0.493 & 0.424 & 0.682 & 0.411 & 0.430 \\
   & Model3 & 0.637 & 0.487 & 0.724 & 0.467 & 0.703 \\
   & Model4 & 0.639 & 0.483 & 0.724 & 0.463 & 0.702 \\
   \cline{2-7}
  & Model5 & 0.481 & 0.429 & 0.682 & 0.403 & 0.416 \\
   & Model6 & 0.452 & 0.419 & 0.657 & 0.380 & 0.475 \\
   & Model7 & 0.495 & 0.467 & 0.701 & 0.437 & 0.664 \\
  \midrule
  \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset3}} & Model0 & 0.885 & 0.806 & 0.829 & 0.793 & 0.811 \\
   & Model1 & 0.814 & 0.815 & 0.840 & 0.851 & 0.872 \\
   & Model2 & 0.814 & 0.812 & 0.837 & 0.851 & 0.872 \\
   & Model3 & 0.838 & 0.819 & 0.850 & 0.809 & 0.839 \\
   & Model4 & 0.837 & 0.818 & 0.849 & 0.808 & 0.838 \\
   \cline{2-7}
  & Model5 & 0.810 & 0.816 & 0.840 & 0.843 & 0.863 \\
   & Model6 & 0.885 & 0.805 & 0.828 & 0.794 & 0.812 \\
   & Model7 & 0.820 & 0.806 & 0.841 & 0.887 & 0.820 \\
  \midrule
  \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset4}} & Model0 & 0.811 & 0.850 & 0.834 & 0.732 & 0.806 \\
   & Model1 & 0.826 & 0.824 & 0.841 & 0.754 & 0.870 \\
   & Model2 & 0.824 & 0.818 & 0.839 & 0.746 & 0.865 \\
   & Model3 & 0.845 & 0.796 & 0.838 & 0.791 & 0.833 \\
   & Model4 & 0.845 & 0.799 & 0.838 & 0.793 & 0.833 \\
   \cline{2-7}
  & Model5 & 0.851 & 0.873 & 0.851 & 0.826 & 0.802 \\
   & Model6 & 0.810 & 0.842 & 0.826 & 0.730 & 0.804 \\
   & Model7 & 0.843 & 0.827 & 0.841 & 0.812 & 0.827 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  %\end{adjustbox}
  \end{table}
  
  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{My table with \textit{ht} option}
    %\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llrrrrr@{}}
    \toprule
    {\textbf{Dataset}} & {\textbf{Model}} & {\textbf{F-1}} & {\textbf{F-2}} & {\textbf{F-3}} & {\textbf{F-4}} & {\textbf{F-5}}\\
    \midrule 
    \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset1}} & Model0 & 0.805 & 0.800 & 0.840 & 0.817 & 0.853 \\
     & Model1 & 0.839 & 0.813 & 0.855 & 0.879 & 0.822 \\
     & Model2 & 0.840 & 0.811 & 0.855 & 0.880 & 0.825 \\
     & Model3 & 0.845 & 0.812 & 0.849 & 0.806 & 0.843 \\
     & Model4 & 0.846 & 0.814 & 0.850 & 0.808 & 0.844 \\
     \cline{2-7}
    & Model5 & 0.840 & 0.817 & 0.857 & 0.879 & 0.818 \\
     & Model6 & 0.807 & 0.891 & 0.835 & 0.816 & 0.857 \\
     & Model7 & 0.828 & 0.803 & 0.844 & 0.889 & 0.828 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset2}} & Model0 & 0.448 & 0.417 & 0.659 & 0.376 & 0.477 \\
     & Model1 & 0.488 & 0.424 & 0.682 & 0.412 & 0.432 \\
     & Model2 & 0.493 & 0.424 & 0.682 & 0.411 & 0.430 \\
     & Model3 & 0.637 & 0.487 & 0.724 & 0.467 & 0.703 \\
     & Model4 & 0.639 & 0.483 & 0.724 & 0.463 & 0.702 \\
     \cline{2-7}
    & Model5 & 0.481 & 0.429 & 0.682 & 0.403 & 0.416 \\
     & Model6 & 0.452 & 0.419 & 0.657 & 0.380 & 0.475 \\
     & Model7 & 0.495 & 0.467 & 0.701 & 0.437 & 0.664 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset3}} & Model0 & 0.885 & 0.806 & 0.829 & 0.793 & 0.811 \\
     & Model1 & 0.814 & 0.815 & 0.840 & 0.851 & 0.872 \\
     & Model2 & 0.814 & 0.812 & 0.837 & 0.851 & 0.872 \\
     & Model3 & 0.838 & 0.819 & 0.850 & 0.809 & 0.839 \\
     & Model4 & 0.837 & 0.818 & 0.849 & 0.808 & 0.838 \\
     \cline{2-7}
    & Model5 & 0.810 & 0.816 & 0.840 & 0.843 & 0.863 \\
     & Model6 & 0.885 & 0.805 & 0.828 & 0.794 & 0.812 \\
     & Model7 & 0.820 & 0.806 & 0.841 & 0.887 & 0.820 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow[c]{8}{*}{\textit{Dataset4}} & Model0 & 0.811 & 0.850 & 0.834 & 0.732 & 0.806 \\
     & Model1 & 0.826 & 0.824 & 0.841 & 0.754 & 0.870 \\
     & Model2 & 0.824 & 0.818 & 0.839 & 0.746 & 0.865 \\
     & Model3 & 0.845 & 0.796 & 0.838 & 0.791 & 0.833 \\
     & Model4 & 0.845 & 0.799 & 0.838 & 0.793 & 0.833 \\
     \cline{2-7}
    & Model5 & 0.851 & 0.873 & 0.851 & 0.826 & 0.802 \\
     & Model6 & 0.810 & 0.842 & 0.826 & 0.730 & 0.804 \\
     & Model7 & 0.843 & 0.827 & 0.841 & 0.812 & 0.827 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    %\end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Here is a image of a page with the correctly-sized table (made with `[H]`):
[image]

And here is a image of a page with the incorrectly-sized table (made with `[ht]`):
[image]

How can I change the location specifiers of the table without breaking the row spacing?

UPDATE: I noticed that this problem comes from using package *setspace* (somehow only works with the *H* table location specifier), but I really need to use this package, otherwise the text is too much condensed.

Comment: Why the -1 vote?

Comment: Can you make a compilable example which reproduces the problem?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: just did that. And on doing it, I realised that this may be some clash with package setspace (apparently only works when table specifier is H...)